# ebXML Message Service Handler for .NET...?

Tags: c#, .net, integration, b2b, ebxml

Currently looking at implementing an ebXML MSH using .NET.

Has anyone done this before, and/or know of any open source .NET examples out there?

Any comments/advice welcome ;-)

Comment: How did you get on? I'm also looking for a way to connect to a 3rd party using ebXML Message Service and .Net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My company was going to use the [Covast](http://www.covast.com/) ebXML adapter for BizTalk. Whilst not a 100% .NET based solution it is one of the few Microsoft focused products that deals with ebXML. I think from memory the license was about $3000 AUD.

In the end we decided to go with an Apache Camel ESB that uses Hermes as the ebXML messaging layer.